# Javascript | decodeURIcomponent

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, ascii

I'm having a lot trouble understanding this. What happens in getForm() is the url is broken down into name / value pairs, it is then passed back and stored into $_GET ?
My understanding after that just breaks down. I don't know why decodeURIcomponent is used or how it works, and I'm not 100% sure what the $_GET[peroperty] line does OR what 'clean' even is and how it can be pushed into an array...

```
var url = document.location.href;
$_GET = getForm(url);
var counter = 0;
var answers = [];
for (property in $_GET) {
     var str = $_GET[property];
     var dec = decodeURIComponent(str);
     var clean = dec.replace(/\++/g, ' ');
     $_GET[property] = clean;
     counter++;
     if (counter > 2 && clean != "") answers.push(clean);
}
```

Comment: What does `getForm(url)` return? Maybe poke around MDN with search terms like [*decodeURIComponent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)  and it's sibling [*encodeURIComponent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and it might start to gel. Or not…

Comment: @RobG it passes in the url and then splits it into name value pairs,then they are inserted into an object, and that object is then assigned to $_GET